# PHP SQL Adding several people to the project

Tags: php, sql

I need help creating a project system to which I can add a few people. What database structure should I create to assign several people to the project?

My database

```
users
 id 
 name
 surname

project
 id 
 name
 desc
 owner
 member
```

Comment: Create a table project_members. (And don't forget foreign keys.)

Answer (score -1):

With a relational database :

```
users
 id 
 name
 surname

project
 id 
 name
 desc
 owner
 member  // Do not store projects users here
```

Create an join table

```
projects_members
 project_id 
 user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use many-to-many relation in order to add many people to the project and to have many people in the project.

You need to add one more table

```
user_project
  user_id
  project_id
```

and delete column `member` from `project` table